# Convert a JsonNode to Object with ModelMapper

Tags: java, json, modelmapper

I tried several times, but I can not solve it and I need help.

I want JsonNode to Object

JsonNode :

```
{
    "usdusd" : 1.00,
    "usdkrw" : 1100
}
```

MyObject

```
public class MyObject {
    private BigDecimal usd;
    private BigDecimal krw;
}
```

How can I mapping using org.modelmapper.ModelMapper? 
JsonNode -> MyObject

Answer (score 0):

This is the implementation through objectmapper:

```
ObjectMapper mapper=new ObjectMapper();
MyObject value=mapper.readValue(jsonNode,MyObject.class);
```

This is the implementation through modelmapper

```
ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();
mapper.getConfiguration().addValueReader(new JsonElementValueReader());
JsonElement responseElement = new JsonParser().parse(json);
MyObject foo = mapper.map(responseElement, MyObject.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Spring Boot (2.4.2). Jackson is the default parser here, so no need of adding any dependency. I am using the following code to convert a JsonNode to My Object using ObjectMapper only (without the need of ModelMapper). Here jsonNode is an instance of com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

...

ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
MyObj myObj = mapper.treeToValue(jsonNode, MyObj.class);
```

Of course it will throw a checked exception called

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException
```

so you need to do "throws" or "try-catch" it mandatorily.

Answer (score 0):

use **@JsonProperty("usdusd")** on field usd, **@JsonProperty("usdkrw")** on field krw to map your filed to the json node. then use ObjectMapper as @Mayank said.